# R Dividing a factor column into several columns that represent several factor levels

Tags: r

I created a large data frame from hundreds of files. The new data frame has ~3,000 rows and ~5 columns. It looks like this:

```
 id  Place Year_2000 Year_2010 Year_2020 Year
 AL_Scen1_10mm.land.csv Putnam 0 0.17 0.19 
 AL_Scen2_5mm.ocean.csv Boykin 0.1 0.3 0.5
```

The id column was creating by taking the filename of each individual file. I would like to divide the id column into 4 different columns that represent the State, Scenario, Limit, and LandType.

There are:
  52 different factor levels for State, 
  4 different factor levels for Scenario, 
  4 different factor levels for Limit, 
  and 2 different factor levels for LandType.

I have looked at other questions, but they do not address my need to create new columns that include multiple factor levels.

Thank you for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF <- df %>% separate(id, 
               c("State", "Scenario", "Limit", "LandType"),
               extra='drop')
head(DF)
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are rarely helpful for others